# Function application: Why is $ used here?

Tags: function, haskell, operators, pointfree

A while ago, I asked a [question about $](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395995/when-should-i-use-and-can-it-always-be-replaced-with-parentheses), and got useful answers -- in fact, I thought I understood how to use it.

It seems I was wrong :(

This example shows up in a tutorial:

```
instance Monad [] where
   xs >>= f = concat . map f $ xs
```

I can't for the life of me see why $ was used there; ghci isn't helping me either, as even tests I do there seem to show equivalence with the version that would simply omit the $. Can someone clarify this for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `$` is used here because it has lower precedence than normal function application.
Another way to write this code is like so:

```
instance Monad [] where
   xs >>= f = (concat . map f) xs
```

The idea here is to first construct a function (`concat . map f`) and then apply it to its argument (`xs`). As shown, this can also be done by simply putting parenthesis around the first part.

Note that omitting the `$` in the original definition is not possible, it will result in a type error. This is because the function composition operator (the `.`) has a lower precedence than normal function application effectively turning the expression into:

```
instance Monad [] where
  xs >>= f = concat . (map f xs)
```

Which doesn't make sense, because the second argument to the function composition operator isn't a function at all. Although the following definition does make sense:

```
instance Monad [] where
  xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
```

Incidentally, this is also the definition I would prefer, because it seems to me to be a lot clearer.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that $ was even lower precedence than (.); I had been mentally parsing lines with (.) in it as separate "chunks," when this is not always the case! I agree that it would have been much clearer to write it how you did, or as: concat $ map f xs

Comment: I prefer "xs >>= f = concat $ map f xs" myself.

Comment: I do too, or in this case: `xs >>= f = concatMap f xs`

Comment: "xs >>= f = flip (join.fmap)" :)

Comment: To add to the noise: (>>=) = flip concatMap -- =)

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to explain why IMHO this is not the used style there:

```
instance Monad [] where
  xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
```

`concat . map f` is an example of so-called pointfree-style writing; where pointfree means "without the point of application". Remember that in maths, in the expression `y=f(x)`, we say that `f` is applied on the point `x`. In most cases, you can actually do a final step, replacing:

```
f x = something $ x
```

with

```
f = something
```

like `f = concat . map f`, and this is actually pointfree style.
Which is clearer is arguable, but the pointfree style gives a different point of view which is also useful, so sometimes is used even when not exactly needed.

EDIT: I have replaced pointless with pointfree and fixed some examples, after the comment by Alasdair, whom I should thank.

Comment: I agree, pointless style can be useful, however I don't like using it when you actually do apply arguments to a function, as in this case.

Comment: Also, if you're not careful you can overdo it, here's some code I wrote yesterday ;-) `maybe id (((sp . ("string " ++)) .) . shows) mx`

Comment: 'concat . map f $ xs" is not pointfree, bind for the list monad written in a pointfree style would be '(>>=) = flip concatMap' or similar. This is one example where the pointfree style is actually very clear. See http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pointfree

Comment: I know this is not point-free, but it is similar to pointfree style; since >>= has reversed arguments, flip is also required (I had forgot about the possibility to use `flip`, that's true).

Answer (score 1):

The reason $ is used here is doe to the type signature of (.):

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> c) -> a -> c
```

Here we have

```
map f :: [a] -> [[b]]
```

and

```
concat :: [[b]] -> [b]
```

So we end up with

```
concat . map f :: [a] -> [b]
```

and the type of (.) could be written as

(.) :: ([[b]] -> [b]) -> ([a] -> [[b]]) -> [a] -> [b]

If we were to use `concat . map f xs`, we'd see that

```
map f xs :: [[b]]
```

And so cannot be used with (.). (the type would have to be (.) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b