# What is the difference between $ (dollar) and $! (dollar exclamation point)

Tags: haskell, syntax

Can anybody explain the difference in Haskell between the operators `($)` and `($!)` (dollar sign vs dollar sign exclamation point)?

I haven't seen the use of `$!` anywhere so far, but while browsing through the Haskell [reference](http://www.zvon.org), I noticed its existence and that it has the exact same definition as `$`. When trying some simple statements in a Haskell interpreter ([GHCi](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/GHCi)), I couldn't find any difference, nor could I find any reference to the operator in the top listed tutorials when searching for `haskell tutorial`.

So, just out of curiosity, what is the difference, if at all?

Comment: HIYF: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=%28%24!%29&format=sherlock

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`($!)` is strict function application. That is, it evaluates the argument before evaluating the function.

This is contrary to normal lazy function application in Haskell, e.g. `f x` or `f $ x`, which first start to evaluate the function `f`, and only compute the argument `x` if it is needed.

For example `succ (1 + 2)` will delay the addition `1 + 2` by creating a thunk, and start to evaluate `succ` first. Only if the argument to succ is needed, will `1 + 2` be evaluated.

However, if you know for sure that the argument to a function will always be needed, you can use `($!)`, which will first evaluate the argument to weak head normal form, and then enter the function. This way, you don't create a whole big pile of thunks and this can be more efficient. In this example, `succ $! 1 + 2` would first compute `3` and then enter the function `succ`.

Note that it is not always safe to just replace normal function application with strict function application. For example:

```
ghci> const 1 (error "noo!")
1
ghci> const 1 $! (error "noo!")
*** Exception: noo!
```

Comment: Last example is more about side effect of `error`. Functional semantic should never be hurt by bangs (the same for `par` and `seq`). Putting bangs may sometimes increase speed/memory and sometimes decrease. And in some special cases it can lead to never-ending calculations `const 1 $! (last [1..])`.

Comment: Well, the printing of the message is a side effect, but the point is that `error` is ⊥ (bottom). Just like a never-ending calculation is ⊥. If you evaluate ⊥ using a `seq`, the semantics of your program change. This is why you should be careful with things like `seq` and `($!)`, it can increase (or decrease) the efficiency of you program, but it could also potentially make it crash where it normally shouldn't have.

Answer (score 7):

See the  [seq](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html) function, which forces the evaluation of a value. 
$! is defined in terms of seq.

[This](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2008/05/bad-strictness.html) is a blog post which shows some nuances of its use.

Comment: Ah, stupid me! It says so on zvon as well in the description of `$!`, but for some reason the equals sign never rang a bell...
Thanks for the link to the blog.

Comment: `f $! x  = x ``seq`` f x` http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Prelude.html#%24%21