# haskell magical code, what's going on here

Tags: haskell, syntax, binary

I'm looking over the Cloud Haskell package's [Encoding.hs](https://github.com/jepst/CloudHaskell/blob/master/Remote/Encoding.hs), and encountered some strange code that I was hoping someone could help me better understand. Included is the necessary code:

```
class (Binary a,Typeable a) => Serializable a
instance (Binary a,Typeable a) => Serializable a

data Payload = Payload
    { 
        payloadType :: !ByteString,
        payloadContent :: !ByteString
    } deriving (Typeable)

serialDecodePure :: (Serializable a) => Payload -> Maybe a
serialDecodePure a = (\id -> 
    let pc = payloadContent a
    in pc `seq`
        if (decode $! payloadType a) == show (typeOf $ id undefined)
        then Just (id $! decode pc)
        else Nothing ) id
```

I'm just curious about what the $! does (I'm guessing just strictly evaluates), and also why we need the id trick (something with lazy evaluation?). Also I am specifically having problems with this line:

```
if (decode $! payloadType a) == show (typeOf $ id undefined)
```

I'm guessing this is seeing if the payloadType is invalid for whatever reason, but if that is the case shouldn't the then and else clauses be switched, ie change:

```
if (decode $! payloadType a) == show (typeOf $ id undefined)
    then Just (id $! decode pc)
    else Nothing
```

to

```
if (decode $! payloadType a) == show (typeOf $ id undefined)
    then Nothing
    else Just (id $! decode pc)
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Yes, `f $! x` is strict application. You may find [this article](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.com/2008/05/bad-strictness.html) enlightening about how adding strictness works.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/2787543/246886

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are correct that `$!` is a strict evaluator.  It's type is identical to `$`, and the only semantic difference is that the second argument is `seq`'d before being passed to the function.

I think the `id` is actually there to help type inference.  Within the function block `(\id -> ...)`, the function `id` is forced to have type `a -> a`, where `a` is not just any type variable, but **the same `a`** as in

```
serialDecodePure :: (Serializable a) => Payload -> Maybe a
```

This is due to this line:

```
Just (id $! decode pc)
```

since this has type `Maybe a`, `id` has the inferred type `a -> a`.  As a consequence, on the line you're looking at,

```
if (decode $! payloadType a) == show (typeOf $ id undefined)
```

`id undefined :: a`, where `a` is again the same as the output.

Now we can get to the type checking.  Since this function is polymorphic and will decode to *any* type, it needs to check that the encoded data is compatible with the type it's decoding to.  What if you encoded a `String` and are trying to decode to an `Int`?  The LHS would decode to "[Char]", which is the TypeRep representation of a String.  The RHS would instead be "Int", the type it's attempting to decode to.  Since they aren't equal, the "else" path is the one that returns `None`.

Rather than this id function type restriction, you could accomplish the same thing with the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension.

Answer (score 4):

Wow, that's some weird-looking code! As you guessed, `($!)` is about strictness:

```
f $! x = x `seq` f x
```

The `id` trick is sneakier, and is all about type restriction. You'll notice that `id` is used twice in the function body. The second time it's used as `id $! decode pc`; this fixes the type of `id` to operate on whatever kind of thing `decode` outputs. The first use is as `typeOf $! id undefined`; since the type of `id` has been fixed already, this fixes the type of `undefined`, so that `typeOf` is applied to a monomorphic argument (and you don't get "ambiguous type" errors). This kind of thing is often done with the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension instead of this trickery, but perhaps they wanted to avoid extensions wherever possible. As for the meaning of this:

```
(decode $! payloadType a) == show (typeOf $ id undefined)
```

...it looks to me like that is checking that the payload matches the type of the thing returned by the call to `decode` in the `then` branch. It seems to make sense to have a `Just` value (i.e. success) when they match, and a `Nothing` value (i.e. failure) when they don't.