# How do I give expressions generic types in a "where" clause?

Tags: generics, haskell, types, where-clause, type-declaration

<sub>*(please excuse the horribly contrived example)*</sub>

What I want to do is specify types in the where-clause:

```
somemap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
somemap f xs = ys
  where
    some = take 5 xs :: [a]
    ys = map f some :: [b]
```

But this causes an error:

```
*Main> :load file.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( file.hs, interpreted )

fil.hs:15:18:
    Couldn't match expected type `a1' against inferred type `a'
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           an expression type signature at file.hs:15:25
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `somemap' at file.hs:12:12
      Expected type: [a1]
      Inferred type: [a]
    In the second argument of `take', namely `xs'
    In the expression: take 5 xs :: [a]

file.hs:16:13:
    Couldn't match expected type `b1' against inferred type `b'
      `b1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           an expression type signature at file.hs:16:24
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `somemap' at file.hs:12:17
    In the first argument of `map', namely `f'
    In the expression: map f some :: [b]
    In the definition of `ys': ys = map f some :: [b]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Whereas if I just specify concrete types, substituting `Int` for `a` and `Bool` for `b`, no problem:

```
somemap :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [Bool]
somemap f xs = ys
  where
    some = take 5 xs :: [Int]
    ys = map f some :: [Bool]
```

So my question is: **How do I specify generic types and type constraints in a where-clause?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Inside the `where` clause, the type variables `a` and `b` are *new* type variables; type variables aren't scoped, so every type signature has a new supply of them, just as if they were defined at the top level.

If you turn on the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension (put `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` at the top of your file), and change `somemap`'s type declaration to:

```
somemap :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

then the `where` clause definitions you specified will work correctly. I think the `forall`s are only required for backwards compatibility, so that code that reuses type variables in `where` clauses for polymorphic values doesn't break.

If you don't want to use an extension, the alternative is to define ugly helper functions to unify the types, like [`asTypeOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:asTypeOf).

Comment: The code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408911/haskell-magical-code-whats-going-on-here is a good example of the confusion that can arise from such "ugly helper functions".