# What is the difference between $! (dollar exclamation point) and !(exclamation point)

Tags: haskell

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2787560/645703 says:

> ($!) is strict function application. That is, it evaluates the
>   argument before evaluating the function.

I know !(exclamation point) is a strictness declaration in Haskell. It looks like both both have something with strict application, but what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something is considered "strict" when it would lead to an exception if passed `undefined`, as in:

```
> :set -XBangPatterns
> let foo b x = if b then show x else "ignore x"
> let foo' b !x = if b then show x else "ignore x"
> foo False undefined
"ignore x"
> foo' False undefined
"*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

But we can't use `!` outside of function declarations. So instead we need to use `$!` as in the example in the link you provided (in this case it is used to replace `$`):

```
> const 1 $ undefined
1
> const 1 $! undefined
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
```

You'll notice also that for `!` you need to use the BangPatterns language extension but you don't for `$!`. It's also useful to note that `$!` is implemented in terms of `!` (though in a slightly weird way and refers to what I guess must be [issue #2273](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2273)).

See the [$! implementation in Prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/src/Prelude.html#%24%21):

```
($!)    :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $! x  = let !vx = x in f vx  -- see #2273
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly: ! is a strictness declaration, so the parameter after ! will be evaluated to weak head normal form(WHNF). $! is strict function application, and it will first evaluate the argument to weak head normal form, and then apply the function. If I am wrong please correct me.

Answer (score 2):

`!` as enabled by the `BangPatterns` extension is always in a pattern, before a binding, like this:

```
add :: Int -> Int -> Int
add !a b = a + b
```

It means "if execution tries to force this pattern case, then reduce the !-ed binding to weak head normal form before evaluating the right hand side of the pattern"

`f $! x` means "if execution tries to force this "f $! x" expression, then proceed by first reducing "x" to weak head normal form, then applying "f" to the reduced "x" ".

In both cases, note that the strictness annotations only express a *conditional* statement. If I have a `f $! x` lying around (where `x` might be a thunk for a complicated computation), if the execution never tries to force `f $! x`, then of course nothing of it will be evaluated.

Comment: Actually, `!` can also appear in datatype declarations, to denote that a constructor function should be strict (to WHNF) in a particular argument. The use in datatype definitions also predates the appearance of "bang patterns".

Comment: what is the difference between add !a b=a+b and add $! a b=a+b ? please give some explanations.

Comment: @MattElson: there is no difference, both are syntax errors. You can do `ghci -XBangPatterns`, then it will accept `let add (!a) b = a + b`, but you cannot `let add $! a b = a + b`.

Comment: "...then reduce the !-ed binding to weak head normal form before evaluating the right hand side of the pattern", what is the right hand side of the pattern in the definition of add?  I guess it is the first parameter a.

Comment: @MattElson by right hand side I mean on the right of "=", namely "a + b" there