# Converting f(x) into f([x]) using decorator in python

Tags: python, functional-programming, decorator, lifting

```
class foo(object):
        def __init__(self,f):
                self.f = f
        def __call__(self,args_list):
                def wrapped_f(args_list):
                        return [self.f(*args) for args in args_list]
                return wrapped_f(args_list)

if __name__=='__main__':

        class abc(object):
                @foo
                def f(a,b,c):
                        return a+b+c

        a = range(5)
        b = range(5)
        c = range(5)
        data = list(zip(a,b,c))
        print(abc.f(data))
```

I wrote this a few years back. When you decorate any function `f(X)` with `@foo` it becomes 
`f(list of Xs)`.

What is this process called? What is it? What is its functional programming name?

Its not currying. I know simple `map9(f,list of Xs)` could have done it.

What are decorators/operation of decorating called mathematically?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but maybe reverse currying is what you search for? See here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5882527/reverse-currying
http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/371

Comment: Maybe but in this case function is still taking single argument.

Answer (score 4):

There are two transformations performed on your original function:

1. it is converted from a function of three arguments to a function that takes a 3-tuple
2. conversion from a function of a 3-tuple to a function that takes a list of 3-tuples

**First transformation**
In Haskell, there is a function called `uncurry`, documented [here](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/uncurry_f.html).  (This is a two-argument version; 3-, 4-, ... versions could be easily created, too).

**Second transformation**
Also in Haskell, there are sets of functions with `lift` in their names.  [Here's](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Lifting) a page on the Haskell wiki about lifting.  I think that page explains it better than I could:

```
Lifting is a concept which allows you to transform a function into a   
corresponding function within another (usually more general) setting.
```

So in your case, you're lifting a function from operating on tuples to operating on a list of tuples.

---

Notes:

- the OP asked for the mathematical name for decorators.  I don't know what that would be, but I've heard that Haskell is supposed to be like executable mathematics, so I think Haskell's terminology is a good starting point. YMMV.
- the OP asked for the FP name of these processes.  Again, I don't know, but I assume that Haskell's terminology is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Decorators just have special syntax, but there are no rules what decorators can return and no mathematical description. They can be any callable after all.

Your function is just a partially applied starmap:

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import starmap

def foo(f):
    return partial(starmap, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a functional language like Haskell, you would do this by partially applying the `map` function to a function which takes a tuple of arguments, resulting in a function which takes a list of argument tuples. As Jochen Ritzel pointed out in another answer, even in Python you can implement this pretty trivially using `functools.partial`.

Therefore I suppose this process is called "partial application of map", or some such thing. I'm not aware of any particular name for this special case.

Answer (score 0):

They are simply called `Decorators`.   What it does *can* be called **`function chaining`** or **`function annotation`**, but I looked around quite a bit and found no special functional/mathmatical name for this process besides those 2 (chaining/annotation).

[PEP Index > PEP 318 -- Decorators for Functions and Methods](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)

> On the name 'Decorator'
>
> There's been a number of complaints about the choice of the name
>   'decorator' for this feature. The major one is that the name is not
>   consistent with its use in the GoF book [11]. The name 'decorator'
>   probably owes more to its use in the compiler area -- a syntax tree is
>   walked and annotated. It's quite possible that a better name may turn
>   up.

Comment: I don't think this question is about generator but about the transformation the specific decorator in the question performs.

Comment: I want to what decorators are called mathematically?