# Why isn't Haskell Partial Application Working?

Tags: haskell, partial-application

My work in Haskell comes in the form of re-working .Net F# projects in Haskell for the fun of it.

I'm parsing a regular Windows configuration file--one key/value pair per line, key separated from value by `=`. This file is very simple and straight-forward, which allows my parsing code to be simple and straight-forward, which I like.

My question is why partial application is not working on the last line of code below. It's obviously working in prior lines and other functions.

```
module Configuration (Config (..), load) where

import Data.Char (isSpace)
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)

data Config = Config { aliases :: [String]
                     , headers :: [String] }

-- This is a naive implementation. I can't decide if I like it better than
-- trim = unpack . strip . pack.
trim :: String -> String
trim = reverse . dropSpaces . reverse . dropSpaces

dropSpaces :: String -> String
dropSpaces = dropWhile isSpace

split _ [] = []
split c cs = [takeWhile (/= c) cs] ++ split c (tail' $ dropWhile (/= c) cs)
  where tail' []     = []
        tail' (x:xs) = xs

load :: String -> Config
load text =
  let ss = lines text
      hs = map getValue $ getLines "Header" ss
      as = split ',' $ getValue $ getLine "AliasList" ss
   in Config { aliases=as, headers=hs }
  where getLines p = filter (p `isPrefixOf`)
        getValue   = trim . drop 1 . dropWhile (/= '=')
        getLine    = head . getLines -- Why isn't partial application working here?
```

The error I'm getting follows:

```
Configuration.hs:30:29:
    Couldn't match expected type `[c0]'
                with actual type `[[a0]] -> [[a0]]'
    Expected type: [a0] -> [c0]
      Actual type: [a0] -> [[a0]] -> [[a0]]
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `getLines'
    In the expression: head . getLines
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not partial application, but function composition that is not working. You can't pass 2 arguments to a function that is part of a function composition.

Comment: I was wondering if it were something as simple as not being able to pass two arguments to a function that is part of a function composition, but I couldn't find that by simple Google searches.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to note is the signature of `getLines`. Since `` p `isPrefixOf` ``  has type `(Eq a) => [a] -> Bool`, `getLines p` has type `(Eq a) => [[a]] -> [[a]]` (based on the type of `filter`). Here `[a]` seems to be `String`, so `getLines p` has type `[String] -> [String]` and `p` thus seems to have type `String`. So in fact, `getLines` has type `String -> [String] -> [String]`.

Lastly, `head` has (specialized) type `[String] -> String`, and you're trying to postcompose it with `getLines`. I would guess you're trying to build a function with type `String -> [String] -> String`, defined by `\p ss -> head (getLines p ss)`. That is, however, *not* what `head . getLines` is!

To see this, consider `f :: a -> b -> c` and `g :: c -> d` (where I mean to say that the `c`s are the same type in both signatures, so I'm not really writing proper Haskell signatures here). Since one often likes to think of `f` as a "function of two variables", one might err and think of `g . f` as being the function `\x y -> g (f x y)` (type `a -> b -> d`). This is not the case: See for example [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5821089/453616) or the concrete example in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4341123/453616) Or even better: Look at [the type of](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#g:10) `(.)` and work out what `g . f` must be yourself! (Hint: [Every function takes precisely *one* argument](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions). What is the type of `f`'s one argument?)

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code) to do this: ``(p `isPrefixOf`)``

Comment: Excellent discussion points! Thank you so much for the thorough response.