# . versus $ in haskell

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Haskell: difference between . (dot) and $ (dollar sign)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign)

Ok I understand that this:

```
f(g(x))
```

can be rewritten:

```
f $ g(x)
```

and can also be rewritten:

```
f . g(x)
```

What I don't fully grasp is where the two DO NOT overlap in functionality. I conceptually understand that they don't fully overlap, but could someone clarify this for me once and for all?

Comment: Look, you actually can'twrite like in your second example. Tryi ghci!

Comment: Also, parens are not needed (and not recommended) for function calls. In summary, the examples should be `f (g x)`, `f $ g x` and `(f . g) x`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
Prelude> :t ($)
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
Prelude> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

`$` applies a function to a value.
`.` composes two functions.

So I can write `f $ g x` which is "apply f to (g of x)" or `f . g $ x` which is "apply the composition of f and g to x". One common style is to pile up dots on the left with a dollar trailing. The reason is that `f $ g $ x` means the same thing as `f . g $ x` but the expression `f $ g` on its own is often meaningless (in fact, possibly a type error) while the expression `f . g` means "the composition of f and g"

Comment: `f $ g` is perfectly possible and well-typed for countless `f` and `g` (consider `(\f -> f 0) $ (\x -> x + 1)`), it's just identical to `f g`. Otherwise, correct.

Comment: @delnan I can't think of a `f $ g` that is well-typed on its own *and* in the context of `f $ g $ x`. But that could  be a failure of imagination.

Comment: edited to take into account your point. thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Additionaly to what was already said, you need the $ as "function application glue" in cases like this:

```
map ($3) [(4+),(5-),(6*),(+4),(*5),(^6)]
--[7,2,18,7,15,729]
```

Neither `(.3)` nor `(3)` will work in the example.

Comment: +1 - great addition to the discussion

Answer (score 1):

"f $ g x" cannot be rewritten to "f . g x". In fact, the compiler won't even accept the second function, because "(.)" has the type "(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)". I.e the second argument must be a function, but "g x" is a value not a function.

Comment: `g x` will be a function for (curried) 2-or-more-ary `g`, e.g. `const 0`.

Comment: @delnan: Yes, but i assumed g was unary from the way he used it.