# What's the meaning of this odd 'chained' lambda (x => () => y)?

Tags: c#, lambda, callback

I just started working on a project with an existing code base. While looking over the project, I found an odd lambda that I'm trying to understand.

Here's the code:

```
SomeFunction(x => () => new Y());
```

I don't understand...

- why there are two `=>` operators in the callback.
- what is the purpose of the `()`.

For reference, here is the method signature of `SomeFunction`:

```
ISomeInterface<T> SomeFunction(Func<IXInterface, T> method);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first lambda is returning a second lambda (a function) that returns a new object, in this case of type `T`.  Recall that functions (i.e. delegates) are first-class objects in their own right.

In an ordinary lambda function, there is a lambda parameter that "encloses" the outer scope, as in this predicate:

```
x => x.SomeMember == true;
```

The `()` is simply a placeholder that says "I don't require a lambda parameter here, since I don't need to refer to the outer scope."  `(x)` and `(x, y)` are also valid forms, so the `()` just means "no lambda parameters specified."

Comment: I'd love to see a practical example.

Comment: @TaW: It's basically a [Higher-order function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5792769 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443285 for some examples of higher-ordered functions.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now. Could the author also have said `x => (() => y)` to mean the same thing?