# How to use '(<)' as a variable?

Tags: haskell

How would I use the greater or less than sign as a variable so that when I enter `Main> mySort (<) [1,5,3,6,4,1,3,3,2]` or `Main> mySort (>) [1,5,3,6,4,1,3,3,2]` it will sort the list from highest to lowest or lowest to highest depending on which sign I chose to enter?

Comment: WHat does ** ( ) ** do?

Comment: Was ment to make it bold

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101710/sorting-in-haskell-with-parameter-using-higher-order-function (someone in your class?)

Answer (score 4):

You can just pass `(<)` in and use it compare each value.

A similar function

```
mySort :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -- Comparator function
       -> [a]
       -> [a]
```

And Haskell is so smart that this already exists as `sortBy`. This lets you pass in a function returning an `Ordering` which is just

```
data Ordering = LT | EQ | GT deriving(...)
```

But you have functions `a -> a -> Bool` so you need to make this into an ordering and then you can use it with `sortBy`.

```
wrap f a b | not $ f a b || f b a = EQ
           | f a b                = LT
           | otherwise            = GT
```

Now you can use this to wrap `(<)`  and `(>)` to lift it to be used with `sortBy`

```
mySort :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
mySort = sortBy . wrap
```

Comment: I think `wrap`'s guards would be nicer as `| f a b = LT`, `| f b a = GT` then `| otherwise = EQ`.

Answer (score 0):

There already is a function in Data.List that does very similar thing to what you want, it is called **sortBy**.
However if you really want to implement it you could use sortBy like this:

```
mySort cop ls = sortBy (\a b -> if (cop a b) then LT else GT) ls
```

or even shorter (using eta reduction):

```
mySort cop = sortBy (\a b -> if (cop a b) then LT else GT)
```

Comment: This is defeats the entire point of having higher order functions...

Comment: @jozefg Could you explain please? You are talking about passing function as an argument? Question I was answering was asking only for < and > so I didn't think it is needed to make it work for all  kinds of functions. If question was to create a sort that accepts comparison function as an operator, then I agree this would not be a good idea.

Comment: Higher order functions let you do this sort of thing generically, what sortBy actually does is take a **function** and use that to produce the ordering, it's type sig is `sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]` This is much lighter weight and more typesafe, using your method you could pass in ` '*' ` or something into your function and get a runtime error with no idea where it came from

Comment: @jozefg You are right, I also missused sortBy. I think it should be ok now