# Haskell - How to use a function that returns 'Maybe Int' as an argument to another function?

Tags: haskell

When I have the two functions:

a)

```
three :: Int -> Maybe Int
three a
 | a == 3 = Just 3
 | otherwise = Nothing
```

b)

```
takeOne :: Int -> Int
takeOne a = (a - 1)
```

how do I call function a as a parameter to function b? i.e How do I let function b accept a 'Maybe Int' in place of an 'Int'?

At the minute when I try

```
takeOne (three 3)
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR - Type error in application
*** Expression     : takeThree (three 3)
*** Term           : three 3
*** Type           : Maybe Int
*** Does not match : Int
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your expected result if `three` returns `Nothing`?

Comment: Use `fromJust` from Data.Maybe

Comment: @Shanth that should only be used when you *know* you will have a Just value. Otherwise, you should really propagate any Nothing values by using fmap.

Comment: @PWright that's right. But here op is sure about its nothingness.

Comment: @Shanth In that specific example, yes. In general, probably not. If we are assuming that the user only cares about this specific instance, then why not just replace takeOne (three 3) with 2? I.e., we should probably assume that the example is constructed to ask about a more general concept and answers, accordingly, should be more general than this specific instance.

Comment: @PWright : alright. Just saying :)

Comment: @Fresheyeball For `takeOne` to return an error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've got a few options, but I'd say the easiest is `fmap`:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Example:

```
> fmap takeOne $ three 3
Just 2
> fmap takeOne $ three 2
Nothing
```

Another option would be to use the function `maybe`, which takes a default value, a function to apply to any value inside the `Just`, and then the `Maybe a` to apply this to.  An example should make it clear

```
> maybe 0 takeOne $ three 3
2
> maybe 0 takeOne $ three 2
0
```

Another alternative if you just want to give a default value is to use the function `fromMaybe` from `Data.Maybe`:

```
> import Data.Maybe
> fromMaybe 0 $ three 3
3
> fromMaybe 0 $ three 2
0
```

---

In Haskell, there is a typeclass called `Functor` defined as

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

There are many, many types that are instances of `Functor`.  In fact, all parametrized data structures are `Functor`s, as are all `Applicative`s and `Monad`s.  The easiest mental model of a `Functor` is that it's just a fancy name for a container.  For lists, `fmap = map`, for example.  All it does is map a function over the elements inside a container.

Some more examples are:

```
> fmap (+1) (Left "error")
Left "error"
> fmap (+1) (Right 1)
Right 2

> x <- fmap (++", world") getLine
Hello
> x
Hello, world

> fmap (+1) [1..5]
[2,3,4,5,6]

> fmap (+1) ("fst", 2)
("fst", 3)
```

Even functions are `Functor`s!  Here `fmap = (.)`, it's just normal function composition:

```
> let lengthPlusOne = fmap (+1) length
> lengthPlusOne "Hello"
6
```

Comment: And, if this is confusing, you might want to check out:

http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids

Comment: Note that you'll frequently see `fmap f $ g` written as `f <$> g` using the function [`(<$>)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Functor.html#v:-60--36--62-) from [Data.Functor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Functor.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, it's really appreciated. I'm struggling to implement `fmap` into my code. The functions I'm using have multiple parameters and as I'm not sure what role the `$` symbol plays I don't know where to put it.

Comment: The `$` function has the following definition: `f $ x = f x`.  What makes it useful is that it has very low precedence in terms of order of operations.  The hand-wavy quick explanation is that `$` computes what's on the right and passes it to what's on the left, so you can write code like `f $ g $ h x` instead of `f (g (h x))`, or even more usefully something like `map (+1) $ filter even $ zip [1..10] $ f x` instead of `map (+1) (filter even (zip [1..10] (f x)))`. Luckily for you, you don't need to implement `fmap` at all, it's already defined for you for many data types. Just use it as is.

Comment: @CharlesDelLar One thing to look out for with `$` is that it works best when what's on the right only takes 1 parameter.  So something like `map $ (+1) $ [1..10]` won't work, while `map (+1) $ [1..10]` will.  There are other explanations of this operator though, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign), which might help make things more clear.

Comment: Does it matter that the parameters of the functions I'm using are data types that I have defined myself?

Comment: @CharlesDelLar Not in the least.  The type of `$` is just `(a -> b) -> a -> b`.  The actual types used can be anything and everything under the sun.  You should be mindful that actually much of what you see in Haskell is defined in Haskell other than a small core of low level stuff like `IO` and primitive types.  The `Maybe` data type has its declaration in plain old Haskell, same with `Either`, `Functor`, and many more.  Just about every function you use that doesn't do IO is written in Haskell as well, like `map` and `filter`.

Comment: @CharlesDelLar For example: `data MyData = MyData Int String`; `f :: MyData -> String`; `f (MyData i s) = show i ++ " " ++ s`; `f $ MyData 1 "test"` would return `"1 test"`.

Answer (score 0):

One other option of course is to write your own.

```
data IAcceptedAMaybeInt = GotAnswer Int | NothingAtTheMoment deriving Show

pleaseAcceptAMaybeInt f g a = case g a of
                                Just b    -> GotAnswer (f b)
                                otherwise -> NothingAtTheMoment
```

Output:

```
*Main> pleaseAcceptAMaybeInt takeOne three 3
GotAnswer 2

*Main> pleaseAcceptAMaybeInt takeOne three 2
NothingAtTheMoment
```