# How to stop Maybe from being passed into another function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, option-type

I have already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387251/haskell-how-to-use-a-function-that-returns-maybe-int-as-an-argument-to-anoth) answer, but it is unclear to me how to apply it in my situation.

I have the following function:

```
designC :: DesignC -> Maybe CDef -> String
designC FirstString _ = "first_string"
designC SecondString _ = "second_string"
designC UnknownString c = getName c
```

The getName function takes a CDef as it's argument. However the above code will not work and has the following error:

```
No instance for (getIdea (Maybe CDef))     
arising from a use of ‘getName’
In the expression: getName c
```

I tried:

```
designC UnknownString c = getName (Just c)
```

but the error shows that this made things worse

```
No instance for (getIdea (Maybe (Maybe CDef)))
```

**How can I pass just the CDef to getName?**

Comment: What do you expect `designC` to do if the `Maybe CDef` is `Nothing`? Should it throw an error, propagate the `Nothing` along or return a default value?

Comment: Are we supposed to know what `getName` and `getIdea` [sic] are? Anyway, I don't. Show us their definitions, please.

Comment: What value exactly do you want `designC UnknownString Nothing` to return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to handle a situation when your Maybe is Nothing.

Either provide some default value

```
defaultValue = ""

designC :: DesignC -> Maybe CDef -> String
designC FirstString _ = "first_string"
designC SecondString _ = "second_string"
designC UnknownString (Just c) = getName c
designC UnknownString Nothing = defaultValue

-- or shorter
designC UnknownString c = maybe defaultValue getName c
```

Or raise an exception

```
data MyException = VeryNastyError

designC :: MonadError MyException m => DesignC -> Maybe CDef -> m String
designC FirstString _ = pure "first_string"
designC SecondString _ = pure "second_string"
designC UnknownString (Just c) = pure $ getName c
designC UnknownString Nothing = throwError VeryNastyError
```