# Haskell : why f1 . f2 xy not working?

Tags: haskell, function-composition, dot-operator

I'm a bit confused concerning the dot operator. I've got the following code (for testing):

```
test :: Int -> Int -> Int
test x y = f1 . f2 x y 
           where f1 n = n+1
                 f2 x' y' = x' * y'
```

And I figured it would first execute (f2 x y) and then f1 on that result, but instead it throws an error. Could anyone tell me the exact definition of the dot operator and what equals *f1 . f2 x y*? (when written without the dot operator)

Best regards,
Skyfe.

EDIT: If the dot operator yields a complete new function I figured the following code should work:

```
test :: Int -> Int -> Int
test x y = f1 . f2 x
           where f1 n = n+1
                 f2 x' y' = x' + y'
```

But also that code returns an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Infix operators always have lower precedence than function application in Haskell, so this

```
f1 . f2 x
```

parses like this

```
f1 . (f2 x)
```

but, `f2 x` is not of type function (well, it could be if f2 returns a function, but that is not so in general, or in your problem).  Since (.) acts on functions, this won't work.

Use ($) instead

```
f1 $ f2 x
```

Comment: Aah thanks I get it! So that means the dot operator creates a new function from 2 functions, but then why wouldn't my 2nd code work? f1 . f2 x would thus be parsed f1 . (f2 x), where f2 x would be a function still expecting one parameter, which would be the y parameter just like f1.

Comment: @user2999349, you need to say `test x =` instead of `test x y =` in that case.

Comment: @user2999349- @luqui beat me to it, the problem isn't the parameters you are passing into (.), it is a mismatch in types in what is expected for the type of `test x y` (should be an Int) and what `f1 . f2 x` actually is (it is `(Int->Int)`).  You can either put the `y` in the RHS (ie- make both sides type `Int`), or remove it from the LHS (ie- make both sides type `(Int->Int)` to make the definition consistent.

Answer (score 2):

One common approach is to combine `(.)` with `($)`:

```
f1 . f2 $ x
```

This can be extended easily to build up longer "pipelines":

```
f1 . f2 . f3 . f4 $ x
```

and then, if you find yourself needing that same combo elsewhere, you need only cut and paste:

```
fs = f1 . f2 . f3 . f4

... fs x ... fs y
```

Answer (score 2):

(I think the other answers come up with `$` too quickly)

As you already know,

```
f1 . f2 x
```

is parsed as

```
f1 . (f2 x)
```

Write

```
(f1 . f2) x
```

instead to do what it reads: compose `f2` and `f1` and then apply this composed function to `x`. Now

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x = f x
```

looks like it is superfluous. Its primary purpose is that it has the lowest precedence, so you can avoid parentheses:

```
foo . bar . baz $ x + y * z = (foo . bar . baz) (x + y * z)
```

See also: [Haskell: difference between . (dot) and $ (dollar sign)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign)