# Why doesn't Haskell accept arguments after a function composition?

Tags: haskell, lambda, higher-order-functions

Considering Haskell has currying functions, we can do this:

```
foo a b = a + b -- equivalent to `foo a = \b -> a + b`

foo 1 -- ok, returns `\b -> 1 + b`
foo 1 2 -- ok, returns 3
```

Declaring the function returning a lambda, just like in the comment, works just fine as well.

But when I compose these functions, like this:

```
foo a b = a + b
bar x = x * x

bar . foo 1 -- ok, returns a lambda
bar . foo 1 2 -- wrong, I need to write `(bar . foo 1) 2`
```

Then it results in an error.

The question is: why are the parentheses around the function composition necessary?

Comment: Erm, _what_ error? We don't know what the error is! Put it here.

Comment: "No instance for (Show (a0 -> c0)) arising from a use of ‘print’". Actually, it's not really an error. I'm saying that using `bar . foo 1 2` doesn't work as I want to.

Comment: But the composition operator gets only two arguments and returns a lambda, ok? Why doesn't it work as a normal function?

Comment: *Why doesn't returning a lambda from function work like the function composition? I mean, in composition I need to put parentheses around the one, and no parentheses are needed when a lambda is returned from function.* What you're asking is unclear... Which *function* are you referring to?

Comment: @Thelost A lambda _IS_ a normal function! There's no difference at all.

Comment: You're probably confusing the function composition operator with `$`: `bar $ foo 1 2` works fine.

Comment: No. I'm sure what I'm saying.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume that you've define the following in GHCi:

```
λ> let foo a b = a + b
λ> let bar x = x * x
```

Based on some of [your follow-up comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547217/why-doesnt-haskell-accept-arguments-after-a-function-composition/27547657#comment43522197_27547657), it seems that you believe

```
bar . foo 1 2
```

to be equivalent to

```
(bar . foo 1) 2
```

However, remember that function application (space) has higher precedence than the composition operator (`.`); therefore

```
bar . foo 1 2
```

is really equivalent to

```
bar . ((foo 1) 2)
```

Now, let's look at the types:

- `.` has type `(b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`; its two arguments are functions (that can be composed).
- `bar` has type `Num a => a -> a`, and is therefore compatible with the type (`b -> c`) of the first argument of `.`.
- `foo 1 2` has type `Num a => a`; it's a (polymorphic) numeric constant, *not* a function, and is therefore *not* compatible with the type (`a -> b`) of the second argument of `.`.

That's why you're getting a type error in `bar . foo 1 2`. What you can do, though, is

```
bar $ foo 1 2
```

because the `$` operator has type `(a -> b) -> a -> b`. See [Haskell: difference between . (dot) and $ (dollar sign)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign?rq=1)

Comment: @Thelost Just to be clear: are you asking why `(bar . foo 1) 2` does work whereas `bar . foo 1 2` doesn't? Note that, if you define `foo a = \b -> a + b`, then `bar . foo 1 2` still doesn't work...

Comment: Exactly! This is my question. Looking to the Haskell's rules, Functions can receive only one argument. Then, I thought that the Haskell looks for this: `bar . foo 1 2` and says that  the foo is receiving the 1, and returning a lambda. Therefore, the composition happens here: `bar . foo 1` and let the `2` out of this.

Comment: @Thelost No. `bar . foo 1 2` is equivalent to `bar . ((foo 1) 2)`, *not*, as you seem to think, to `(bar . foo 1) 2`. Function application (space) has the higher precedence, so what gets passed as the second argument to `.` is the value of `foo 1 2`.

Answer (score 6):

`bar . foo 1 2` is `bar . (foo 1 2)` not `(bar . foo 1) 2`

There's nothing mysterious going on here related to lambdas. Say we expanded the application of `foo` to 1:

```
bar . foo 1 2
bar . (\b -> 1 + b) 2
```

Now, we apply the lambda to the 2

```
bar . 3
```

And there is your problem.

Conversely, if we place the parentheses correctly, we evaluate it like this:

```
(bar . foo 1) 2
(bar . (\b -> 1 + b)) 2
(\x -> bar ((\b -> 1 + b) x)) 2
bar 3
```

Comment: This is not answering the question of _"Why doesn't returning a lambda..."_

Comment: @AJFarmar I tried making it clearer why that is not the question.