# $ operator in Haskell gives data constructor error

Tags: haskell

`1:([2])` works as expected.

`1:$[2]` gives `` <interactive>:15:2: Not in scope: data constructor `:$' ``

I thought the `$` operator parenthesizes everything after it:
[Haskell: difference between . (dot) and $ (dollar sign)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign)

What is going on?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `$` operator is not syntax, it's just a normal function like every other.  When you write

```
1 :$ [2]
```

The first problem the compiler sees is that `:$` appears as its own operator (consider `+ +` versus `++`, these are very different things), but `:$` is not defined anywhere.

If you were to write

```
1 : $ [2]
```

Then the compiler doesn't understand what to do since you have two operators right next to each other, this isn't allowed, just as `1 + * 2` isn't allowed.  These expressions simply don't make any sense.  The `$` operator is actually just defined as

```
f $ x = f x
```

But it has a low precedence, like [Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Mnemonics) for arithmetic operator precedence, so that you can chain operations more easily.  It does not actually insert parentheses into an expression.

Comment: I think this answer deserves more credit than mine, but so far only one other person has joined with my sentiment.

Comment: @AndrewC Your answer was still good, you got it posted first, and you mentioned operator sections, something I failed to.  It's not like I mind the rep, at this point I don't get any more privileges, and [we're pretty closely matched on the haskell tag anyway](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45578/top-100-users-in-a-given-tag) =P

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I learned many new things today.

Answer (score 10):

You put `$` between a function and a value, and it applies the function to the value.

`1:` isn't a function, but `(1:)` is, so you can do `(1:) $ [2]` but not `1: $ [2]`.

(The error you got was because without spaces, the compiler thinks `:$` is one thing, not two, and operators starting with `:` are data constructors, just like functions starting with capitals are data constructors.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and explanation of the error message. Can you explain why `:1` is not a function? If `1:[2]` gives `[1,2]`, that means `:` is `: :: a -> [a] -> [a]`. Through currying `1:` would give `[a] -> [a]` which is a function. Even if this is incorrect, how did `()` turn it into a function?

Comment: It's called an operator section, and it's a form of partial application. Operators take two arguments, but if you supply one of them and put it in brackets the compiler sees it as a function of the one remaining argument, and you can do whatever you can normally do with a function. Examples: `(+7)` is a function that adds seven, `("Hi, "++)` adds at the front of a string, and `(' ':)` puts a space at the front of a string.

Comment: Thank you very much for the term. I found more information here: https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator

Answer (score 6):

`$` doesn't literally place parentheses around arbitrary code, but changes the order in which functions are evaluated (like parentheses do, too).