# Haskell recursion stack overflow

Tags: haskell, recursion, stack-overflow, guard

I am pretty new to Haskell, so sorry for the question. But - how to get rid of the endless recursion and not been overflown. This is the code:

```
foo :: Integer -> Integer
foo x
    | x == 1         = 1
    | x <= 0         = error "negative number or zero"
    | odd x          = foo 3 * x + 1
    | x `mod` 2 == 0 = foo x `div` 2
    | otherwise      = x
```

**EDIT**:

```
foo :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
foo x
    | x == 1         = (1, z) 
    | x <= 0         = error "negative number or zero"
    | odd x          = foo  (3 * x + 1) . inc z
    | even x         = foo  (x `div` 2) . inc z
    | otherwise      = (x, z)
  where z = 0

inc :: Integer -> Integer
inc i = i + 1
```

I believe that the code is self-explanatory, but yet : If x is even then divide it with 2 otherwise 3*x + 1. This is part of the famous Collatz problem.

Comment: You could also use `even` instead of the `mod 2` test. And it seems like your `otherwise` case will never be reached.

Comment: In your edit, an expression like `f x . g y` associates like `(f x) . (g y)` instead of `(f x . g) y` because function application binds tighter than any operator. You could use `$` here (in fact, you might be mixing up `$` with `.`), but you could also just make the parentheses explicit and not use `.` or `$`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function application has higher precedence than many other operations, so `foo 3 * x + 1` is actually calling `foo 3`, then multiplying that result by `x` and adding `1`, which looks like where your infinite loop might be.

Changing it to the following should fix that:

```
| odd x          = foo $ 3 * x + 1
| x `mod` 2 == 0 = foo $ x `div` 2
```

Comment: could you explain what `$` is?

Comment: You could also write this as `f (3 * x + 1)`. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign) for a longer description of `$`.

Comment: When I want to increment it using `.` to count the number of times `foo` has been applied, what else should I do? It is in the edit part.

Comment: I could imagine doing something like `odd x = inc . foo $ 3 * x + 1`, and then defining `inc (x, i) = (x, i + 1)`, which makes `inc` have type `(Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer)`.