# Why does the Haskell `show ` function give me trouble here?

Tags: haskell

I am just a few days into Haskell and learning it from Learn You a Haskell for a great good. While trying out one of the 99 Haskell problems, I ran into the following error while loading my function into ghci.

The problem asks to write a function `elementAt k x` which takes a number k, a list x and extracts the `kth` element of the list x.

Here is my function

```
elementAt :: Int -> [a] -> a
elementAt k x
  | k < 0            = error "You have passed a negative index"
  | null x           = error "Cannot extract from an empty list"
  | (length  x) < k  = error "The array contains fewer than " ++ (show k) ++  "elements"
elementAt 0 (x:_)    = x 
elementAt k (_:xs)   = elementAt (k-1) xs
```

On loading this function into ghci I get the error

```
   Couldn't match expected type `a' with actual type `[Char]'
     `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
         the type signature for elementAt :: Int -> [a] -> a at fun.hs:77:14
   Relevant bindings include
     x :: [a] (bound at fun.hs:78:13)
     elementAt :: Int -> [a] -> a (bound at fun.hs:78:1)
   In the expression:
     error "The array contains fewer than " ++ (show k) ++ "elements"
   In an equation for `elementAt':
       elementAt k x
         | k < 0 = error "You have passed a negative index"
         | null x = error "Cannot extract from an empty list"
         | (length x) < k
         = error "The array contains fewer than " ++ (show k) ++ "elements"
```

The trouble seems to lie with the way I have used the `show` function, but I 
don't see why. On removing the `show` call the function seems to compile and 
work perfectly.

Answer (score 9):

You will need to put parentheses around your error message in line 5.

Currently your implementation is equal to this one:

```
(error "The array contains fewer than ") ++ show k ++  "elements"
```

While you most likely wanted it to do this:

```
error ("The array contains fewer than " ++ show k ++  "elements")
```

You can also use the [($)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign) syntax like so:

```
error $ "The array contains fewer than " ++ show k ++  "elements"
```

Answer (score 8):

According to [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-280003.4), `f x ++ g y` parses as `(f x) ++ (g y)`. In your case,

```
error "The array contains fewer than " ++ (show k) ++  "elements"
```

parses as

```
(error "The array contains fewer than ") ++ (show k) ++  "elements"
```