# Difference between using $ and . to chain functions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Although I often read that it is advisable to chain functions in the following manner:

```
f1 . f2 . f3 . f4 $ value
```

I find that I like the following chaining method better:

```
f1 $ f2 $ f3 $ f4 value
```

Other than the visual difference, is there a functional or performance difference between the two?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, although I'll (like last time this happened) point out that the top answer to the duplicate doesn't contain the reasoning that convinces *me* (see the answers by sclv and Antal Spector-Zabusky for that).

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen None of the answers in the "duplicate" say anything about functional or performance differences, which is what I'd like to know. They only talk about the difference in intention and in type. I can I can infer that the two are functionally and performance-wise equivalent.

Comment: Oh right. With GHC inlining, they should normally be compiled to the same thing.