# $ Dollar Sign Not Allowed in Place of Parentheses

Tags: haskell

Replacing the parentheses in this function:

```
isInteger x = x == fromInteger (round x)
```

with a dollar sign operator:

```
isInteger x = x == fromInteger $ round x
```

raises an error.

What are the limitations of using the $ operator?

Comment: The best SO question doesn't handle this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign

Comment: It's just a low-precedence infix operator. You get an error about this for the same reason `3 * 5 + 7` means `(3*5) + 7` rather than `3 * (5+7)`.

Comment: @DanielWagner can you please define an 'infix operator' as you understand the term?

Comment: [The Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-180002.4) is the canonical reference. Any sequence of symbols is an infix operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$` has extremely low precedence, lower than `==`, lower than *everything*. Your attempt is parsed as

```
isInteger x = (x == fromInteger) $ (round x)
```

that is, it attempts to apply a `Bool` as a function. You could write

```
isInteger x = x == (fromInteger $ round x)
```

but that doesn't really save any parentheses; it just shifts them.

---

If you *really* want to get rid of the parentheses (or at least, really move them aside), you can take advantage of the fact that `(-> r)` is an applicative functor, which in brief means that `f <*> g == \x -> f x (g x)`. Replacing `f` with `(==)` and `g` with `fromInteger . round`, you get

```
isInteger = (==) <*> fromInteger . round
```

because

```
x == fromInteger (round x) -> (==) x (fromInteger (round x))
                           -> (==) x ((fromInteger . round) x)
                              ----    ---------------------
                               f   x (          g           x)
```

Comment: This is a good clarification of Learn You a Haskell's explanation:  "you can imagine a $ being sort of the equivalent of writing an opening parentheses and then writing a closing one on the far right side of the expression."

Comment: While we're quoting LYAH, I should also mention "[functions] are rarely used with the applicative style outside of code golf". It's clever, concise, and barely readable :)

Comment: @chepner It's sort of readable if you think of it as the `Reader` monad.

Answer (score 1):

This is the beginning of the accepted answer in the question you linked in the comment:

> The $ operator is for avoiding parentheses. **Anything appearing after
>   it will take precedence over anything that comes before.**

Taking this into account, `isInteger x = x == fromInteger $ round x` becomes `isInteger x = (x == fromInteger) (round x)`, so you're taking the result of `x == fromInteger` (which is of type `Bool`) and applying it to `round x`. This clearly doesn't make sense.