# Recursive implementation of LCM in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write my own multiple LCM function in Haskell, one that computes the LCM of all the elements in a given list. I'm trying to use the property lcm(a,b,c) = lcm(a,lcm(b,c)) to make it recursive. Here is what I could come up with so far, but it is giving me errors which I'm not able to understand.

```
 multLCM xs 
    | length(xs) == 2 = lcm head(xs) last(xs)
    | length(xs) > 2 = lcm head(xs) multLCM(drop 1 xs)
```

Can someone help me improve this function so that it works?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Completely sidestepping the syntax issues: since `(lcm, 1)` forms a monoid over the natural numbers, you should consider `multLCM = foldr lcm 1`.

Comment: @DanielWagner wow! that is just beautiful (sorry i'm reacting to this 3 years late)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parentheses do not denote function application in Haskell. E.g., these are equivalent.

```
lcm head(xs) last(xs)
lcm head xs  last xs
```

That is, the function `lcm` provided the arguments `head`, `xs`, `last`, and `xs`.

Parentheses *do* allow you to specify function application *by grouping a function with its arguments*.

```
lcm (head xs) (last xs)
```

Comment: Can you please let me know when I can use `$` and `.` in place of parentheses? I always found that confusing

Comment: @KoundinyaVajjha Have you seen [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/haskell-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign#1290727)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use pattern matching to deconstruct the list:

```
multiLCM (x:xs) = lcm x (multiLCM xs)
multiLCM [x]    = ???
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to complete your answer. I don't want my `multiLCM` to be defined for single element lists and want it to be just the usual `lcm` for two element lists. Can pattern matching be done in this case? Something like `x:y:xs` maybe?

Comment: Why? I can't think of any good reason not to define multiLCM for a single element list.