# Couldn't match `[Int]' with `Integer -> Int' but works in GHCI

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell so this question should be fairly trivial to most Haskell programmers:
I've got a function `digits :: Integer -> [Int]` which converts an integer to a list of its digits (123 to [1,2,3]). To now get the sum of those digits I enter `sum $ digits 123` in ghci and everything works, it outputs 6. As soon as I create the function in a file as follows, however, I get an error. It probably has to do with the fact that ghci infers a type for 123, but that is not enough so I can fix the problem.

The function in a text file:

```
digitalSum :: Integer -> Int
digitalSum = sum $ digits
```

and the error:

```
* Couldn't match type `[Int]' with `Integer -> Int'
  Expected type: Integer -> Integer -> Int
    Actual type: Integer -> [Int]
* In the second argument of `($)', namely `digits'
  In the expression: sum $ digits
  In an equation for `digitalSum': digitalSum = sum $ digits
```

Comment: See also: [*Haskell: difference between . (dot) and $ (dollar sign)*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/940382/2751851)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `sum $ digits 123` works in GHCi (just as it will in a Haskell file), `sum $ digits` (which could just as well be written `sum digits`) won't work in GHCi either.

The problem is that `sum` takes a list of numbers, but `digits` is not a list, it's a function.

You want either `digitalSum x = sum $ digits x` or `digitalSum = sum . digits`. Here `.` is the function composition operator, which creates a function out of two existing functions (as opposed to `$`, which takes a function and its argument, not another function).

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the argument

```
digitalSum :: Integer -> Int
digitalSum x = sum $ digits x
```

Alternatively, you can use function composition

```
digitalSum :: Integer -> Int
digitalSum = sum . digits
```