# Haskell first principles get function with type declaration, don't understand answer on GitHub

Tags: haskell

Studying Haskell. Like it. Like the book, but stuck on types, typeclasses.
given type declaration

```
co :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
co = undefined  -- (obviously)
```

Question in book: Design function (answer on GitHub)

```
co = ($)
```

Yes it compiles but

1) Why?

2) What does this function do and why does it typecheck as it does. Just want to understand rather than just remember.

Comment: co is a function that takes a function from b->c and returns a function that takes a function from a->b and returns a function that takes an a and returns a c. Meaning that you can define any function that matches that type signature.

Comment: No, it doesn't compile. See also [difference between . and $](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940382/791604).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Yes it compiles but

It doesn't compile because it is not type correct:

```
/tmp/so.hs:2:6: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘c’ with ‘a -> c’
      ‘c’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          co :: forall b c a. (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
        at /tmp/so.hs:1:1-36
      Expected type: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
        Actual type: ((a -> b) -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
    • In the expression: ($)
      In an equation for ‘co’: co = ($)
    • Relevant bindings include
        co :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c (bound at /tmp/so.hs:2:1)
  |
2 | co = ($)
```

Informally, `co`'s first argument is a function that transforms values of type `b` to values of type `c`.  The second is a function that transforms values of type `a` to values of type `b`.  The final argument is a value of type `a`.  From here it is apparent you can apply the second argument to the third, obtaining a `b` and then apply the first argument, obtaining a value of type `c`.

So long as you understand the syntax of function application things should be apparent from here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured that I could do with studying types and typeclasses again, just to make sure I get the routine in. Thanks for answering this. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Following your answer I distilled the following and it typechecks!!!
co :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c

co = a where

     b = a

     c = b

     a = a

Comment: @Madderote While that will typecheck, It won't evaluate to anything because you have defined `a` to be equal to itself and `co` to be equal to `a`. `a` being equal to itself means you have formed an infinite loop (or possibly an exception explaining it otherwise would be an infinite loop).