# Why is the return type of my Function a -> Int

Tags: haskell

I'm having a problem with my homework, where I have to write a program, which behaves like `wc`.
My current approach is the following:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.UTF8 as UTF8

numBytesUtf8 :: String -> Int
numBytesUtf8 = BS.length . UTF8.fromString

help = "Wrong number or wrong arguments provided.\n\
    \Possible arguments are: [l, w, c, b, ll]\n\n\
    \options:\n\
    \    -l  -> Return line count\n\
    \    -w  -> Return word count\n\
    \    -c  -> Return character count\n\
    \    -b  -> Return byte count\n\
    \    -ll -> Return character count of the longest line"

getLongestLine l r
    | r == []                = return l
    | length next > length l = getLongestLine next rest
    | otherwise              = getLongestLine l rest
    where
        next = head r
        rest = tail r

getLongestLineLength :: [Char] -> a -> Int
getLongestLineLength f = length . words . getLongestLine h t
    where
        l = lines f
        h = head l
        t = tail l

handleArgs :: [[Char]] -> [Char] -> IO ()
handleArgs args f
    | head args == "-l"  = print . length . lines $ f
    | head args == "-w"  = print . length . words $ f
    | head args == "-c"  = print . length $ f
    | head args == "-b"  = print . numBytesUtf8 $ f
    | head args == "-ll" = print ( getLongestLineLength f )
    | otherwise = putStrLn help
```

However currently I get the following error:

```
    • No instance for (Show (a0 -> Int)) arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In the expression: print (getLongestLineLength f)
      In an equation for ‘handleArgs’:
          handleArgs args f
            | head args == "-l" = print . length . lines $ f
            | head args == "-w" = print . length . words $ f
            | head args == "-c" = print . length $ f
            | head args == "-b" = print . numBytesUtf8 $ f
            | head args == "-ll" = print (getLongestLineLength f)
            | otherwise = putStrLn help
   |
43 |     | head args == "-ll" = print ( getLongestLineLength f )
   | 

                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm still new to this language and got surprisingly far till now. But I don't know what to do with `a -> Int` and nor how to print it.

Any Help and other Tips are appropriated :)

Comment: `return` does not do what you think it does. Try to write down the type you think `getLongestLine` *should* have. Is that the type it *does* have? And then [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940382/791604) for the other half of what's wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
getLongestLine l r
    | r == []                = return l
    ....
```

`return` here injects `l` into any monad, making the type of `getLongestLine` to be of the form

```
Monad m => something -> something -> m (something)
```

Now, this is an incident: you likely did not intend to do that. Unfortunately, since you also did not tell GHC what the type of `getLongestLine` was intended to be, GHC inferred the unexpected type above and moved on, causing problems later on in the program. With a type signature on `getLongestLine`, you would have got a type error here.

You were quite unlucky, since the wrong `return` could have caused a type error, but did not in this case.

Indeed, later on the monad is chosen to be `(->) a` since you use composition

```
length . words . getLongestLine h t
```

This causes the type

```
getLongestLineLength :: [Char] -> a -> Int
```

to have an additional unwanted `a` argument, and makes `getLongestLineLength` to take two arguments instead of one (the second one is passed to `getLongestLine`, and ignored there).

When you finally pass only one argument, GHC finally complains.

What to do:

1. Don't use `return` unless you are working with monads. Use `l` instead of `return l`.
2. Always annotate the types of your functions, so that GHC can complain early when something's wrong, instead of much later on after having inferred the unexpected types.

There are several other issues in your code, and you will probably need to make some significant change. I'd suggest you split the string in words early with `words`, and then pass the result `[String]` to the rest of your program. Instead of computing the longest line, and then computing its length, compute the length first, and then take the maximum.

```
longestWordLength :: String -> Int
longestWordLength = maximum . map length . words
```

Not tightly related to your problem, but general suggestions:

1. Don't use `head`, `tail`, `l==[]`. Use pattern matching instead of guards whenever possible.
2. Turn on warnings with `-Wall` and solve them. This would have reported the missing type sisgnature to `getLongestLine`, which caused the misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me a lot. I can already see the red line with haskell :)