# Haskell IO-Monad error upon explicitly stating parameter for 'show'

Tags: haskell, io-monad

Although I feel like a have a good understanding of Haskel IO and Monads, I am having a hard time understanding the following error message.

Consider the following simple function in Haskell

```
testf :: Show a => a -> String
testf x = show x
```

I tried implementing a variant that prints to the console by using an IO Monad

```
printtoscreen :: Show a => a -> IO()
printtoscreen x = putStrLn . show x
```

However, this yields the following error:

> Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘a0 -> String’
>         Expected type: a0 -> String
>           Actual type: String

The correct version should omit explicitly stating the `x` parameter

```
printtoscreen :: Show a => a -> IO()
printtoscreen = putStrLn . show
```

I understand why the last code snippet works, but I cannot make sense out of the error message of the second code snippet, considering that it will also return a string to `putStrLn`

So why should the `x`parameter be omitted in the `IO()` variant?

Comment: `putStrLn . show x` means `\y -> putStrLn (show x y)`, so you implemented a function with `printtoscreen x y = putStrLn (show x y)`. This thus means that `show` should have type `Show a => a -> b -> String`, but of course the type is `Show a => a -> String`.

Comment: makes sense, `putStrLn (show x)` indeed does the trick! Thanks a lot, turns out the mistake is out of the scope of IO Monads

Comment: The issue here is that `putStrLn . show x` is parsed as `putStrLn . (show x)` instead of `(putStrLn . show) x`. This is because function application `show x` has the highest precedence than any binary operator: that's what makes `1 + f x` correct without additional parentheses.

Comment: Probably not strictly a duplicate, but reading the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/what-is-the-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign) should help you understand better what's going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.`, the function composition operator, expects a function. `show x` however is not a function; it's an evaluated value (of type `[Char]`) by the time it's given to `.`.

You'd have to use the function application operator instead:

```
printtoscreen x = putStrLn $ show x
```

Answer (score 3):

> So why should the `x` parameter be omitted in the `IO ()` variant?

This has nothing to do with `IO ()` itself. You here use function composition. Indeed, the [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.) function is defined as:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) f g x = f (g x)
```

It is thus used to combine two functions `f` and `g` in a new function that first applies `g` to a parameter, and then `f` to the result of `g x`.

If you write:

```
printtoscreen x = putStrLn . show x
```

then the `(.)` function will resolve this to:

```
printtoscreen x = \y -> putStrLn (show x y)
```

or thus easier to read:

```
printtoscreen x y = putStrLn (show x y)
```

This would mean that `show` should have a type <s>`Show a => a -> b -> String`</s>, but it has type [**`show :: Show a => a -> String`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:show), hence the error.