# What is the '$' operator?

Tags: daml

I come across some examples in the Daml documentation where the operator '$' is being used, but cannot fully understand its purpose.

Example:

```
submit alice $ create User with username = alice, following = []
```

Is it the same as `do`, like in:

```
submit alice do
  create User with username = alice, following = []
```

?

Comment: This answer applies to Daml as well as Haskell :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/1290727/3314107 Hope it helps, happy Daml'ing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` operator is a substitute for parenthesis. The example

```
submit alice $ create User with username = alice, following = []
```

is the same as

```
submit alice (create User with username = alice, following = [])
```

---

To complete, the `do` is used to declare a code block (more than one line of code):

```
test = scenario do
  alice <- getParty "Alice"
  bob <- getParty "Bob"
  ...
```

However, it can also be used in a single line of code:

```
submit alice do create User with username = alice, following = []
```