# Rewrite using higher order functions

Tags: haskell

This code displays a list of the second elements of every tuple in xs based on the first element of the tuple (x).

For my assignment, I should define this in terms of higher order functions map and/or filter.

I came up with

```
j xs x = map snd . filter (\(a,_) -> a == x). xs
```

Comment: `xs` is a list, not a function, so the composition `stuff . xs` does not make sense. You can instead use something like `f . g . h $ xs` for `f (g (h xs))`.

Comment: not strictly a duplicate, but useful reading here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/what-is-the-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign

Comment: If you can use `concatMap` instead of `map` and `filter`, the Haskell Report tells you how to desugar [list comprehension](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by using parthesis and remove the last dot (`.`) before the `xs`:

```
j :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> a -> [b]
j xs x = (map snd . filter ((a,_) -> a == x)) xs
```

here we thus construct a function between the parenthesis, and we use `xs` as argument. If you use `f . x`, then because of [**`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.), it expects `x` to be a function and it constructs a new function, but in your case `xs` is an argument, not another function to a use in the "chain".

The `(a, _) -> a == x`, can be replaced by `(x ==) . fst`:

```
j :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> a -> [b]
j xs x = (map snd . filter ((x ==) . fst)) xs
```