# Dot notation for function composition

Tags: haskell

Sorry for a newbie question.
Suppose I have:

```
square :: Integer -> Integer
square x = x * x
```

I can do a function composition with parentheses:

```
sumsquares :: Integer -> Integer
sumsquares n = sum (map square [1..n])
```

But I'd like to use the dot notation.  I'd thought this would work:

```
sum . map square [1..n]
```

but it throws an error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘a0 -> t0 c0’ with actual type ‘[Integer]’
    • Possible cause: ‘map’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘map square [1 .. n]’
      In the expression: sum . map square [1 .. n]
      In an equation for ‘sumsquares’:
          sumsquares n = sum . map square [1 .. n]
```

Neither works the (f.g)(x) logic, namely:

```
sum . square map [1..n]
```

What am I not getting, and what's the correct way of using the dot notation in this case?

Comment: Just to point out an extreme use of composition here, replace `[1..n]` with its functional equivalent `enumFromTo 1 n`. Then you can write `sum (map square (enumFromTo 1 n))`, which you can more easily(?) break down into `(sum . map square . enumFromTo 1) n` (`n` is passed to `enumFromTo 1`, whose return value is passed to `map square`, whose result is passed to `sum`. ) Then `sumsquares = sum . map square . enumFromTo 1` in point-free style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `(.)` operator is for composing *functions*, not values, and what it returns is a *function*, not a value. This is because `f . g` is defined as the function which you get as running `g` on its input, then running `f` on the result of that:

```hs
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
f . g = \a -> f (g a)
```

Given this, let’s look at your non-working example again, which I will re-bracket to make the situation a little clearer:

```hs
sum . map square [1..n]
== (sum) . (map square [1..n])
```

Immediately, we can see a problem: `map square [1..n]` is not a function! This means we cannot run it on an input, which in turn means that `sum . map square [1..n]` would make no sense.

So what does make sense? Well, we could do `sum . map square` instead. Now both of the arguments of `(.)` are functions: `sum` sums its input (which must be a list of numbers), and `map square` applies `square` to each element of its input (which must be a list of numbers). Thus, their composition makes sense, the types all line up, and we can use `(.)` with no problems. We can then feed an input to this composite function, by doing `(sum . map square) [1..n]`.

Another option is to use `($)` rather than `(.)`. This operator is defined as follows:

```hs
f $ x = f x
```

That is, `($)` simply applies the function on its left to the value on its right! This might seem a bit useless… but the nice thing about `($)` is that it has a very low precedence, lower than almost anything else in Haskell. In short, this means that it has the effect of ‘bracketing’ everything to its right. Thus, it’s fine to write:

```hs
sum $ map square [1..n]
```

…because this is equivalent to:

```hs
sum (map square [1..n])
```

…which is what you’re trying to do. (For more on the difference between `(.)` and `($)`, I refer you to [What is the difference between . (dot) and $ (dollar sign)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382) .)

Comment: Thank you, this is a great explanation.  I was slowly wisening up to this idea, hence my 2nd candidate (in my original post): ```sum . map square [1..n] ```  What I didn't expect is how things are parenthesized.  I think it'd made more sense if it were ```(sum . square) map [1..n]```.   But anyway, thanks again!

Comment: @AlexKay You’re welcome! The general principle is that function application binds tighter than operator application — this is why you can do things like `length x - 1` and similar.

Comment: This is a subtle point, thank you for pointing it out.  I just learned about Haskell (been under a rock I guess!) and what appeals to me is its pure functional approach.  So I don't indend on doing anything like ```length x - 1``` if I can help it.

Comment: @AlexKay Why would you avoid expressions like `length x - 1`? Purely functional or not, all languages need *some* way of manipulating numbers! Admittedly that precise expression doesn’t come up all that much, but I could easily imagine doing similar things, like e.g. `map (\a -> maximum l - a) xs`.

Comment: You are right.  I really don't have any specific reasons to avoid number manipulation other than stylistic/philosophical.  I am sure I'll need and use it.

Comment: @AlexKay Perhaps you may be thinking of *index* manipulation specifically, which is rather common in imperative languages but almost absent from functional languages (thanks to the presence of `map`/`foldr`/`filter` etc., as well as the use of direct recursion). But numerical computations more generally are necessary everywhere.

Comment: Yes, @bradrn, that's exactly it.  Your insights have been spot on!