# Xmobar commands stuck on 'Updating...'

Tags: haskell, xmonad, xmobar

#### Background

I am new to Haskell and trying to get the `xmobar.hs` to work (as I import colours into the bar via pywal's `colors.hs` file as directed in the file itself). I have managed to get this working, as well as a number of modules. Unfortunately, I have run into a few issues, described below. I accept these are likely entirely due to my unfamiliarity with the language.

In terms of installation, Xmonad was installed via Stack, on Arch Linux x86_64.

Please find all relevant files at the bottom of this question.

#### Problem

The following occurs when restarting xmonad, either via the terminal, or through the shortcut `mod + q`

1. Upon running xmobar, both custom scripts (using `Run Com`) and inbuilt plugins do not work without a `$` between Run and the plugin name (except for `Run XMonadLog`)
2. Removing this `$` throws an error causing xmobar to not run
3. When investigating the cause in the terminal by running `xmobar -x 0 ~/.config/xmonad/xmobar.hs`, I am given the following; `The function ‘Run’ is applied to four value arguments, but its type ‘(Interface -> Args -> Rate -> Monitors) -> Runnable’ has only one`, upon trying to carry out the command `Run Network`, for instance
4. Even *if* a `$` is included in all relevant commands, `Run Com`'s behaviour is seemingly erratic; sometimes xmobar displays the output, sometimes it stays on `Updating...`
5. As the script relies on the output from `date` being polled and manipulated each second, I thought this may be the issue. However, testing [`MarqueePipeReader`](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/doc/plugins.org#user-content-headline-72) which is simply reading text sent to a file in `/tmp/`, also renders the same issue

I did note some (older) answers here referring to [`XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.18.0/docs/XMonad-Hooks-DynamicLog.html) but as seen in the documentation, this is now apparently a compatibility wrapper for more modern modules, both of which are used in the file below.

#### xmonad.hs file

This takes heavily from the official Haskell [tutorial](https://xmonad.org/TUTORIAL.html), changing very little.

```hs
import XMonad

import XMonad.Util.EZConfig
import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops

import XMonad.Actions.RepeatAction

import XMonad.Util.Loggers
import XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers
import XMonad.Hooks.StatusBar
import XMonad.Hooks.StatusBar.PP

import Colors

import XMonad.Layout.ThreeColumns
import qualified XMonad.Layout.Magnifier as Mag

main :: IO ()
main =  xmonad 
        . ewmhFullscreen 
        . ewmh 
        . withEasySB (statusBarProp "xmobar /home/user/.config/xmonad/xmobar.hs" (pure myXmobarPP)) defToggleStrutsKey
        $ myConfig

myConfig = def
    {
        modMask             = mod4Mask -- rebind mod to super
    }
    
myLayout = tiled ||| Mirror tiled ||| Full ||| threeCol 
    where
        threeCol    = Mag.magnifiercz' 1.4 $ ThreeColMid nmaster delta ratio 
        tiled       = smartBorders $ Tall nmaster delta ratio
        nmaster     = 1     -- default number of windows in master pane
        ratio       = 1/2   -- default proportion of screen occupied by master pane
        delta       = 4/100 -- percent of screen to increment when resizing panes
    
myXmobarPP :: PP
myXmobarPP = def
    {
        ppSep               = color2 " • "
    ,   ppTitleSanitize     = xmobarStrip
    ,   ppCurrent           = wrap (color3 "[ ") (color3 " ]")
    ,   ppVisible           = wrap " " " "
    ,   ppHidden            = color6 . wrap " " " "
    ,   ppHiddenNoWindows   = color7 . wrap " " " "
    ,   ppUrgent            = color6 . wrap (color5 "!") (color5 "!")
    ,   ppOrder             = \[ws, l, _, wins] -> [ws, wins]
    ,   ppExtras            = [logTitles formatFocused formatUnfocused]
    }
    where
        formatFocused   = wrap (color3    "[") (color3    "]") . color2 . ppWindow
        formatUnfocused = wrap (color7 "[") (color7 "]") . color3    . ppWindow

        -- windows' title should not exceed certain length
        ppWindow :: String -> String
        ppWindow = xmobarRaw . (\w -> if null w then "untitled" else w) . shorten 30

        color1, color2, color3, color4, color5, color6, color7, color8 :: String -> String
        color1      = xmobarColor Colors.color1 ""
        color2      = xmobarColor Colors.color2 ""
        color3      = xmobarColor Colors.color3 ""
        color4      = xmobarColor Colors.color4 ""
        color5      = xmobarColor Colors.color5 ""
        color6      = xmobarColor Colors.color6 ""
        color7      = xmobarColor Colors.color7 ""
        color8      = xmobarColor Colors.color8 ""
```

#### xmobar.hs file

This is a modification from the official [repo](https://codeberg.org/xmobar/xmobar/src/branch/master/etc/xmobar.hs). Again, very little is changed here.

```hs
import Xmobar
import Colors

config :: Config
config = defaultConfig { overrideRedirect = True
  , font              = "M PLUS 1 Code Regular 10"
  , additionalFonts   = [ "Font Awesome-6 Regular 12" 
                        , "Noto Emoji Regular 12"
                        ]
  , bgColor           = Colors.color2
  , fgColor           = "#f8f8f2"
  , alpha             = 100
  , position          = TopHM 36 40 40 8 0
  , lowerOnStart      = True
  , pickBroadest      = False
  , persistent        = False
  , hideOnStart       = False
  , iconRoot          = "."
  , allDesktops       = True
  , textOutputFormat  = Ansi
  , commands          = [ Run Network "wlan0"   [
                                                  "-H","32",
                                                  "--low",Colors.color5,
                                                  "--normal",Colors.color6,
                                                  "--high",Colors.color7,
                                                  "-t","<fn=1>\xf1eb</fn>  <rx> KB/s | <tx> KB/s"
                                                  ] 
                                                  10
                        , Run $ Com "/bin/bash" ["-c", "/home/user/clock/sh/clock.sh"] "clock" 1
                        , Run XMonadLog
                        ]
  , sepChar           = "%"
  , alignSep          = "}{"
  , template          = "   %wlan0%}%XMonadLog%{%clock%   "
}

main :: IO ()
main = configFromArgs config >>= xmobar
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: xmobar gets stuck on updating if xmonad is not sending anything. Don't start xmobar manually, let xmonad start it and pipe status to it. If you want to restart it,  restart xmonad itself.

Comment: `$` is generally used to avoid parenthesis. If you want to remove it, write `Run (Com ...)`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940382/what-is-the-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign

Comment: Hi @rajashekar and thank you for your comment. Sorry, what I had meant to include was that this behaviour of being stuck on `Updating...` occurs even when restarting xmonad (either view the terminal, or the keyboard shortcut `mod + q`). I will update the question accordingly. Would you happen to know what might be causing this behaviour under these circumstances?